# Using GRASS in Python script QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I am creating a Python script in QGIS 3 and I want to use the processing module. I want to transform my raster file to a vector file with the GRASS algorithm r.to.vect. My problem here is that the output I am getting is always empty. The way I am running the algorithm looks like this:

```
    param = {"input": path_to_some_raster_file,
             "type": 2,
             "output": some_tmp_file,
             'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 0
             }

    vector = processing.run('grass7:r.to.vect', param)
```

But if I use the same parameters in the processing toolbox then the desired output is generated. What am I doing wrong with my Python attempt?

Comment: From the menubar, go to `Processing > History`. This will show you how the parameters for the tool should be used when running it from the console or script.

Comment: That still doesn't help me with my problem. I even copied the whole command from the history and run it in the qgis console and the result remains the same unfortunately....

Comment: I use version 3.4.4

Comment: Empty as in you receive an output but it contains no data or you do not receive any output (in which case maybe use `processing.runAndLoadResults()` instead of `processing.run()`)?

Comment: Empty as in an output which contains no data. If I use `processing.runAndLoadResults()` then I get a `QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition` object.

Comment: But the output file is still empty

Comment: Sorry but can't reproduce your problem, it works fine for me in the GUI and from the console.

Comment: Check if the current user has permissions to the directory of the output.

Comment: The directory of the output is `/tmp/`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues using the processing module. I solved doing like this:

```
####### Initialize you input and output layers ########

input_layer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_some_raster_file,string_with_layer_name,'ogr')
output_path = path_to_some_tmp_file   #Full path with file name AND EXTENSION
output_layer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_some_tmp_file,string_with_layer_name,'ogr') 

#NOTE if your output layer is a vector layer, use QgsVectorLayer instead

####### Set your parameters ########

param = {"input": input_layer, ########### This line was changed
             "type": 2,
             "output": output_path, #########This line was changed
             'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 0
             }

#NOTE pass the input layer directly, but set as output the file path, and not the layer

####### Run the algorithm ########

processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:r.to.vect', param) ###########This line was changed

####### Reload your output layer ########

output_layer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_some_tmp_file,string_with_layer_name,'ogr')
```

In this way, the output_layer should contain the results of your processing algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running grass geoalgorithms from say a python virtual environment, you need to have the same exact `os.environ` variables as the qgis GUI application's python environment. In a `.pth` file under `.pyenv/lib/python3/site-packages/qgis.pth` you could have the following (for MacOS):

```
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/python
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/etc/python
/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins
import os; os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = '/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/PlugIns'; os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH'] = '/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS'; os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/'; os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/lib/:/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/'; os.environ['GISBASE'] = '/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/'; os.environ['USER'] = '<YOUR USER>'; os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'; os.environ['HOME'] = '/Users/<YOUR USER>'; os.environ['SHELL'] = '/bin/zsh'; os.environ['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'] = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.<STRING>/Listeners'; os.environ['XPC_SERVICE_NAME'] = 'org.qgis.qgis3.5780'; os.environ['XPC_FLAGS'] = '0x0'; os.environ['LOGNAME'] = '<YOUR USER>'; os.environ['GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR'] = '/Users/<YOUR USER>/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/gdal_pam/'; os.environ['GRASS_PAGER'] = 'cat'
```

Example of running the grass geoalg after `QgsApplication` and Processing initialization in the external python app:

```py
processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:v.split")
params = {
    "input": <unix path to layer>,
    "length": 30,
    "units": 1,
    "vertices": None,
    "-n": False,
    "-f": False,
    "output": <path>,
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
    'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER': -1,
    'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER': 0.0001,
    'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER': 0,
    'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO': '',
    'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO': '',
    'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT': True,
}
LOGGER.info(params)
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
LOGGER.info("Running geoalg")
res = processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:v.split", params, feedback=feedback)
LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------")
LOGGER.info("Results of grass7.v.split:")
LOGGER.info(res['output'])
LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------")
return res['output']
```